# segmentation fault on glGenBuffersARB(1, &_VertexBufferObject);

Tags: opengl, segmentation-fault, mingw, fault, glew

I have been trying to make an asteroids clone using openGL and have gotten totally stuck on a segmentation error I am unsure how to fix. It seems to happen on the usage of the function glGenBuffersARB(). If I comment out the lines using the vertexbuffer, the program compiles and runs fine (but obviously with nothing rendered). I am using the minGW compiler on eclipse with the gdb debugger and trying to use extensions so I can support versions of OpenGL earlier than 1.5.

```
glGenBuffers(1, &_VertexBufferObject);

glBindBufferARB( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, _VertexBufferObject ); // Bind The Buffer

glBufferDataARB( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, U8VertexCount*3*sizeof(GLfloat), quad,GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB );
```

GLuints are declared as private in a header like this:

```
GLuint _VertexArrayObject;

GLuint _VertexBufferObject;

int U8VertexStride;

int U8VertexCount;
```

gdb traces are here: [gdb trace](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=h3npeUGf)

Comment: Did you actually *load* the extensions by initializing GLEW? Also, buffer objects have been core OpenGL since **1.5**, not 3.0.

Comment: I believe I have initialized GLEW correctly at the beginning using glewInit(), as it is done on the GLEW site. I must have gotten mixed up with when it was made core, i'll edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: Are you setting the GL version before you initialize glew? printing out the function pointers as well can help understanding what is going on. glBufferDataARB vs. glBufferData etc. I think glew will map functions based on what your hardware supports unless you specify gl version before glewInit (using glfwOpenWindowHint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem. It would appear that declaring and using an object was not working the way I had intended. I was declaring the objects as:
        CObj Obj; 
and calling draw like this: 
        Obj.Draw(); 
when I switched to declaring it as a pointer: 
        CObj * Obj; 
and initialising it like this: 
        Obj = new CObj(); 
then using:
        Obj->Draw(); 
started to work as i thought it should. I am unsure why this is the case and would appreciate it if anyone is able to clear this up for me.

Comment: Your object is being created before you enter main, as it is a global (at least according to the gdb trace). So your glew initialization has not happened yet.